# cascading dropdowns from mysql with javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

EDIT: Solution at the bottom of this first entry.

I've been scouring SO for a good day or two now and am not having any luck coming up with getting my dynamic drop downs working.

I have a form.  The first dropdown is the customer field.  What I want is when the customer is selected in the drop down, the terms associated with that customer are selected in the second dropdown.  The Second dropdown always has the same options no matter what customer is chosen, its a matter of which of those options are "selected" for that particular customer.

Here is what it looks like.

```
Dropdown1 (customer)
---------
Acme Corp
Contoso Inc
Smithville

Dropdown2 (terms)
---------
NET15
NET30
NET45
```

I want dropdown2 to change to the terms associated with that customer in the mysql database.

I can't figure out if I should leave the dropdown options in the form itself and use javascript to call a php file to find out which is selected for that customer -or- if I should simply remove the entire options selection from the form and have javascript call that like I show in my work below.

Here is what I in the form for my two dropdowns, the second is from javascript with div.

```
<td><select name="company" onchange="getTerms('terms');">
<option value="" selected></option>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['company']."\">".$row['company']." (".$row['first']." ".$row['last'].")</option>"; } ?></select></td>

<td><div id="terms"></div></td>
```

And here is my php file that is supposed to be called from javascript.  What this does is get the options for the customer and selects the option that is selected.  If I run this directly in the browser with ?id=acme corp it works fine so I know the php is working.

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect.php";


$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * from netterms ORDER BY days ASC") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT terms FROM customer WHERE company = '$_GET[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
  echo "<option value=\"".$row3['days']."\""; echo($row['terms'] == $row3['days']?' selected="selected"':null)?>><?php echo $row3['name']."</option>";

}
?>
```

And finally, here is my attempt at the javascript/jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getTerms(div){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<select name='terms'>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "</select>";
     }
      document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newdiv);
   }

 xmlhttp.open("GET", "customertermsdropdownquery.php?id=", false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

What I am seeing is that everytime dropdown1 is changed, a new (additional) dropdown2 appears on the screen.  I don't want multiple dropdowns appearing all over the page, just want the options in the dropdown to refresh.  Also, I can't figure out how to pass ?id= to my php file from xmlhttp.open if you could help me out would be great!  thanks.

SOLVED:

After several days of trying to get this to work, I stumbled upon a solution on another site.  Here is the code.  What is important here is the careful use of div tags with table tags.  It goes like this which is not shown below in this authors code.

For me the td tags had to be here and not in the php.  However, my select tags are in the php.  I really hope this is of value to someone searching.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Ajax to load the php script every time the first select changes.

Adapted from [sending http request with ajax each time select box is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171361/sending-http-request-with-ajax-each-time-select-box-is-changed) :

I tried adapting the answer to your question but I can't really test it:

```
$("#company").live('change',function() 
{
    var selectVal = $('#company :selected').val();


    var $terms = $('#terms').html('');

    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'customertermsdropdownquery.php',                         
      data: "id="+selectVal,                                                     
      dataType: 'GET',                
      success: function(data)         
      {

              $terms.append(data);

      } 
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm having a look now, I think basically instead of loading the php file via .load() using Ajax XMLHttpRequest would be more appropriate

Comment: also I'm not sure that $("#company").val will return anything before it is actually submitted...

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171361/sending-http-request-with-ajax-each-time-select-box-is-changed

Comment: I saw that one but it was missing a little code for me to think it through.  You mentioned changing the onclick to onchange.  I added this to my select but no go <select name="company" id="company" onchange="#company();">  Is company the name of my function, I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think my script is firing the php, don't know how/why.

Comment: You don't have a function name as your script will execute every time the select is changed. forget about the "onchange" as the jquery solution handles the change

Comment: I tried your script but it didn't work.  Regarding the $terms.append, you have option value in there but my option value is already in the php.  What I don't understand is exactly how do I get my full php to appear between the select tags.  How does the script know where to place the data ?

Comment: well that's the $terms.append, as $terms is assigned to the html inside your #terms.(is your target ) but you probably need some change in your PHP as well

Comment: if you change dataType to 'GET' instead of JSON?

Comment: Also I think in the original he must be storing his results in JSON, which is what the whole function at the end is. You'll have to change that

Comment: Unfortunately its still not working, but your script looks very good.  Is there an easy way to test that it is firing when the first dropdown is selected?

Comment: I added window.alert("sometext"); after the terms.append and it did not fire after changing the first dropdown labled name="company" and id="company"

Comment: Please confirm, is #company :selected obtaining the value inside value="" or is it obtaining the text between the <option></option> tags as the text doesn't match what's inside value="" and I want to be sure.

Comment: I've had some moderate success rewriting this with jquery.  Please have a look at the original posting and I have editted it with my new work.  Getting close!