# Assistance with a Search Function in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am developing a Tour and Travel website and I have an option to allow my users to search Tours based on Region, Country and Duration.

Currently, the search option which I have developed allows to search tours and show results if all the search parameters match. For example, if a Tour is listed under Region- Africa, Country- Ethiopia and Duration- 5 Days, I have to select all the parameters to show up the Tour. But I want to modify the search option so that:

- There would be a Select All option for Region, Country and Duration.
  If someone searches using Select All option for all the three
  parameters it would show all Tours available in the database.
- If someone selects a Region only with the other two as Select All, it
  would show only those tours which are listed under that Region. Same
  with Country and Duration.
- If someone selects only two parameters Like Country and Duration with
  the third option as Select All, it would show only those tours which
  are listed under the selected Country and Duration. Same with Region
  and Duration.

Here is my [Database Structure](http://s29.postimg.org/5nzgu97lj/db_new.jpg)

The PHP code which I am using now is:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("byp");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $region=$_POST['region'];
        $country=$_POST['country'];
        $duration=$_POST['duration'];

        $tour = mysql_query("select * from byp_tour where region='$region' and country='$country' and duration='$duration'");
        $tourNum = mysql_num_rows($tour);

        if($tourNum >0){

            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($tour)){

                $tour_name = $result['tour_name'];
                $tour_detail = $result['tour_detail'];

                echo "Tour Name: $tour_name";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "Tour Detail: $tour_detail";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No Tour Found";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BYP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="byptest.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>Region</label>
                <select id="region" name="region">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">South East Asia</option>
                    <option value="2">Africa</option>
                    <option value="3">Europe</option>
                    <option value="4">America</option>
                    <option value="5">Australia</option>                               
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Country</label>
                <select id="country" name="country">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">Cambodia</option>
                    <option value="2">Thailand</option>
                    <option value="3">Vietnam</option>
                    <option value="4">Myanmar</option>
                    <option value="5">Laos</option>
                    <option value="6">Ethiopia</option>
                    <option value="7">France</option>
                    <option value="8">New York City</option>
                    <option value="9">Melbourne</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Duration</label>
                <select id="duration" name="duration">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">5 Days</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that is an issue, just something you haven't developed yet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I have edited the subject. This is not an issue. I need assistance developing it as I am new to PHP Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possibilities to follow on your code.

You can let the 0 index option on the selects to be "All", instead of being "Select".

E.g.

The regions select

```
<select id="region" name="region">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">South East Asia</option>
    <option value="2">Africa</option>
    <option value="3">Europe</option>
    <option value="4">America</option>
    <option value="5">Australia</option>                               
</select>
```

will be transformed into

```
<select id="region" name="region">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">South East Asia</option>
    <option value="2">Africa</option>
    <option value="3">Europe</option>
    <option value="4">America</option>
    <option value="5">Australia</option>                               
</select>
```

Another possibility is to create a new option with a specific index, e.g., 9999;

This way you can modify your query in order to select all the elements depending on your selection.

The code should be modified to:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("byp");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $region=$_POST['region'];
        $country=$_POST['country'];
        $duration=$_POST['duration'];

        //define the index for the All option
        $optionAllValue = 0; //add here the option index value used for the 'All' option
        //define the where clause for the query
        //in order to avoid many conditions verifications, we start it as 1=1
        $whereClause = "1=1";

        //now we check if the option selected for each field is not the value defined for the option 'All'
        //this is just an example, and the best would be to create a function to avoid the replication of code 
        if($region != $optionAllValue)
        {
            $whereClause = $whereClause." and region='$region'";
        }
        if($country != $optionAllValue)
        {
            $whereClause = $whereClause." and country='$country'";
        }
        if($duration != $optionAllValue)
        {
            $whereClause = $whereClause." and duration='$duration'";
        }

        $query = "select * from byp_tour where ".$whereClause;

        //original query select * from byp_tour where region='$region' and country='$country' and duration='$duration'"
        $tour = mysql_query($query);
        $tourNum = mysql_num_rows($tour);

        if($tourNum >0){

            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($tour)){

                $tour_name = $result['tour_name'];
                $tour_detail = $result['tour_detail'];

                echo "Tour Name: $tour_name";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "Tour Detail: $tour_detail";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No Tour Found";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

The entire modified example can be found below:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("byp");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $region=$_POST['region'];
        $country=$_POST['country'];
        $duration=$_POST['duration'];

        //define the index for the All option
        $optionAllValue = 0; //add here the option index value used for the 'All' option
        //define the where clause for the query
        //in order to avoid many conditions verifications, we start it as 1=1
        $whereClause = "1=1";

        //now we check if the option selected for each field is not the value defined for the option 'All'
        //this is just an example, and the best would be to create a function to avoid the replication of code 
        if($region != $optionAllValue)
        {
            $whereClause = $whereClause." and region='$region'";
        }
        if($country != $optionAllValue)
        {
            $whereClause = $whereClause." and country='$country'";
        }
        if($duration != $optionAllValue)
        {
            $whereClause = $whereClause." and duration='$duration'";
        }

        $query = "select * from byp_tour where ".$whereClause;

        //original query select * from byp_tour where region='$region' and country='$country' and duration='$duration'"
        $tour = mysql_query($query);
        $tourNum = mysql_num_rows($tour);

        if($tourNum >0){

            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($tour)){

                $tour_name = $result['tour_name'];
                $tour_detail = $result['tour_detail'];

                echo "Tour Name: $tour_name";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "Tour Detail: $tour_detail";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No Tour Found";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BYP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="byptest.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>Region</label>
                <select id="region" name="region">
                    <option value="0">All</option>
                    <option value="1">South East Asia</option>
                    <option value="2">Africa</option>
                    <option value="3">Europe</option>
                    <option value="4">America</option>
                    <option value="5">Australia</option>                               
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Country</label>
                <select id="country" name="country">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">Cambodia</option>
                <option value="2">Thailand</option>
                <option value="3">Vietnam</option>
                <option value="4">Myanmar</option>
                <option value="5">Laos</option>
                <option value="6">Ethiopia</option>
                <option value="7">France</option>
                <option value="8">New York City</option>
                <option value="9">Melbourne</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Duration</label>
            <select id="duration" name="duration">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">5 Days</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have noticed your Selects are interdependents. It means you need to update the current options in cascade after on of the Selects are modified. To be able to do execute the cascading you can reference other questions on StackOverflow: [cascading dropdowns from mysql with javascript and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980072/cascading-dropdowns-from-mysql-with-javascript-and-php)

Comment: One more question. If I add multiple region, country or duration to a tour, the search doesn't work. For example, a Tour ABC is having two countries assigned to it (CDE & XYZ). When I search with CDE or XYZ in both the cases, it shows No Tour Found. Any solution to that?

Comment: It depends on the way you are defining your tables' registries and the way you are retrieving the information. The best is to have another table to identify that your tours can be related to different countries. E.g. byp_tour_countries with 2 fields: tour_id and country_id. This way you remove the country code from the table byp_tour and execute the selects looking into this new table.

Your select would look like:

Comment: `SELECT * FROM byp_tour where tour_id in (select tour_id from byp_tour_country where country_id = '$country')`

and you need to replace your where line from:
`$whereClause = $whereClause." and country='$country'";`
to
`$whereClause = $whereClause." and tour_id in (select tour_id from byp_tour_country where country_id = '$country')";`

Answer (score 0):

You have to build up your query depending on what variables are set. You could do something like:

```
$where = '';
if (!empty(($duration)) {
    $where = " AND duration='$duration'";
}
if (!empty($country)) {
    $where = " AND duration='$country'";
}
if (!empty($duration)) {
    $where = " AND duration='$duration'";
}
$where = substr($where, 5);
$sql = "select * from byp_tour" . ($where ? " WHERE $where" : '');
$tour = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im no PHP whiz but I would first in your HTML form you would want a "Select All" (unless that's what you already mean by "Select")

If you did "Select All" Value = "0" Then after you check for form submission with your:

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

YOu would then need if statements to check for any field that has a Value of "0". If a field is Set to 0 you would then want to remove that part of your database query.

For Ex. If Region = Select All then in your query remove region='$region'

That way you are not returning 0 results as your Region field should not have any region of 0.

Hope that kind of makes sense.