# Onchange select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dreamweaver

I have 2 select menu :

```
<select name="nama_paket">
 <?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_qpaket['nama_paket']?>"><?php echo $row_qpaket['nama_paket']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_qpaket = mysql_fetch_assoc($qpaket));
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($qpaket);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($qpaket, 0);
$row_qpaket = mysql_fetch_assoc($qpaket);
 }
?>
</select>
```

and

```
<select name="harga">
<?php
do {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_qpaket['harga']?>" ><?php echo $row_qpaket['harga']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_qpaket = mysql_fetch_assoc($qpaket));
?>
</select>
```

when we select the first select menu the second select menu change automatically? Thanks

Comment: change how ?? what conditions ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Check this [question] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171361/sending-http-request-with-ajax-each-time-select-box-is-changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change it Dynamically when according to 1st selected value, you need to use ajax in order to do this

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31617905/4238528) explain it

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `select name="hagra"` via AJAX **after** selecting `select name="nama_paket"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery [.change()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345490/onchange-select-menu) event for this. Like:

```
$('select[name=nama_paket]').change(function(){
  // your code you can set different value to second select box
})
```